# select from db sql query

Tags: sql, select

I have this query :

```
$query = mysql_query ("SELECT *
                         FROM saledb.application
                       WHERE app_id = (
                                       SELECT app_id
                                         FROM saledb.applicationdetails
                                        WHERE is_hot = '1'
                                      ) LIMIT $Kvet,$Zet
                      ");
```

And I have the following error:

> Unable to save result set in
>   /home/lemondo/lemondosales.itnovations.ge/content/tpl/gtpl/main.php on
>   line 68

When I changing select item with MAX(app_id) it works but i need show all results. i know where is problem mysql cant choose in one query meny ID but i need alternativ query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `IN` predicate instead of `=` like os:

```
SELECT * 
FROM saledb.application 
WHERE app_id IN
  (SELECT app_id 
   FROM saledb.applicationdetails 
   WHERE is_hot = '1');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM saledb.application WHERE app_id IN (SELECT app_id FROM saledb.applicationdetails WHERE is_hot = '1') LIMIT $Kvet,$Zet");
```

That should do the trick. If you leave '=' and the subquery returns more than one row, you wil get that error. To match all the lines in saledb.application that have the app_id in the result set you need to use "IN" :)